# CSS: Possible to do position:fixed offset center div?

Tags: css, debugging, positioning

First of all, have a look at this example of the layout I'm trying to achieve (below)

[image]

Basically, I have a standard center div (gray) with the typical `margin: 0 auto`.  My problem is that I have a background image (on the white overflow area) that is `<div id="stripes">` with the following CSS

```
background: url(foo) top center repeat;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

This background is applied BELOW the `HTML` level of the document to the `#stripes` div.

What I'm having trouble with is setting up the red div below.  The plan is for it to stay visible at all times via `position: fixed` however, I can't use % based `right: xx%; top: 0` because the pattern must line up with the striped pattern, so a few pixels offset will create a visible and obvious "seam" on the page.

Here is a look at the effect with the stripes included:

[image]

Comment: What is the background of the `red div`? Why can't it be transparent and have the stripes from the page background show though? I'm having trouble visualising the problem. If you could somehow clarify, it would help you get an answer.

Comment: @thirtydot - the background of the red div is a very large photo.  Hypothetically, it could be transparent, but it is a masked photo of a person - load time on this type of PNG image would be pretty killer :/ ... just checked now - would be 354Kb  :( - JPG is only 107Kb

Comment: Could you split the photo into two parts? The larger left part could stay as `jpg`, and the small hanging right part could be a `png` with the required transparency to make it work.

Comment: Not a bad idea... but still I know how to do this with `position: absolute` but is it possible to have a `position: fixed` div with this kind of center offset?

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm still not grokking your problem fully. Do you have a live page I could take a look at? Or if not, try making a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Brian, your moderator flag says that you solved this. Can you post your solution, and accept it as the correct answer two days from now?  This way everyone benefits.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - solution below... cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this was to create two divs.  On the top layer, I used a standaard `width: 960px; margin: 0 auto` div and then at the end of the document I created another div with the same styles meant to act as a container for the photo (red div above).  Inside of the second div I nested a `<div id="photo_bg">` div.  This div used the following styles:

```
#photo_bg{
background: url(foo.jpg) top right no-repeat;
overflow: visible;
position: fixed;
right: 50%;
top: 0;
width: 1014px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

the parent div was called `#stripes`

```
#stripes {
    background: url("images/bg_striped_repeat.jpg") repeat scroll center top transparent;
    height: 9999px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```